# Team City - Trigger build when other projects finish successfully?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-server

I would like to trigger a build on Team City that runs when any other projects it depends on build successfully with a certain tag.

Each of those projects are artifact dependencies, and they are marked to use the latest version of each project with that tag.

**My question is: Can I trigger a build on the main project only when a successful build occurs with that tag in any of the other projects?** The way I understand it, if I set a trigger for each of the sub projects' builds the main project will always try and build from the last tagged builds, even if the triggered build doesn't have said tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem I was having by using Triggers via a scheduled trigger to run every 10 minutes 
(a chron command with the following parameters: `0,0/10,*,*,*,?,*`) 
and then setting the "Trigger only if watched build changes" under Build Changes. Under that same section I set the build to be watched, set the drop-down to "Last build with specified tag", and set the tag to the one I wanted to key off of.